# Racket: get same random element from list in 2 different functions

Tags: racket

I want to pick a random element from list1, remove it from list1, and add it to  list2.
`(define list1 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)
 (define list2 '(9 10)`
Now my problem is, that i use 2 functions to update the lists.
list1 will get a random element removed and list2 will get a random element appended but its not always the same element.
How can I make it that list2 gets the element added, that list1 got removed and then repeat these steps until list1 is empty?
Thanks a lot in advance

```scm
#lang racket
(define list1 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8))
(define list2 '(9 10))  

(define (select_random list)
  (car (shuffle list)))  

(define (update_list list)
  (remove (select_random list) list))  

(define (addToList list1 target_list)
  (append (list (select_random list1)) target_list))
```

Comment: You pass the index to both? You need to copy before you remove. It would help to see some code.

Comment: added code. I shuffle the list and then take the first element out of it. Problem is that its a random element whenever i call the functions. What do you mean by "copy before you remove"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to select one element at random to be used several places is to do it outside of the functions:

```scm
(define (select-random lst)
  (car (shuffle lst)))
```

Now you need to use the element to do your stuff:

```scm
(define (remove-element element lst)
  (remove element lst))  

(define (add-element element lst)
  (cons element lst))
```

So in your loop you can do something like this:

```scm
(let loop ((list1 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))
           (list2 '()))
  (if (null? list1)
      list2
      (let ((element (select-random list1)))
        (loop (remove-element element list1)
              (add-element element list2)))))

; ==> (2 1 5 4 10 7 6 8 9 3)
```

Notice that `remove-element` and `add-element` are really just synonyms for `remove` and `cons`. They don't add any value but change the name. Thus you can just omit them:

```scm
(let loop ((list1 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))
           (list2 '()))
  (if (null? list1)
      list2
      (let ((element (select-random list1)))
        (loop (remove element list1)
              (cons element list2)))))
```

In reality this is just a very complicated way to do `(shuffle '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The loop looks great, one thing I'm still missing is how I get access to the lists let's say after one loop.     (remove-element element lst) => '(1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10) and (add-element element lst) => '(2).

Comment: @User91 In the `let` body before the `loop` call, but it does not include the base case.